# Proof that $\mathcal L^2 \supsetneq \mathfrak B^2$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathfrak L^d$ be the $\sigma$ -algebra of all Lebesgue-measurable subsets and $\mathfrak B^d$ the one of the Borel sets in $\mathbb R^d$.
I want to prove that $\mathfrak L^2 \supsetneq \mathfrak B^2$ which shall be done by three "subproofs":

$1)$ We write $\mathbb R^d$ in the form $\mathbb R^d =\mathbb R^p \times \mathbb R^q$ and respectively an element $x\in \mathbb R^d$ in the form $x=(x_p,x_q)$ with $x_p \in \mathbb R^p, x_p \in \mathbb R^q$. Let $\mathcal M \subseteq \mathbb R^p$. Show that $\mathcal M \times \{0\}$ is a Borel-set, that means $\mathcal M \times \{0\} \in \mathfrak B^{p+q}$, if and only if $\mathcal M$ is a Borel-set ($\mathcal M \in \mathfrak B^p$). Here, $0 \in \mathbb R^q$ denotes the zero vector in $\mathbb R^q$. For the proof, nothing from the theory of measurable functions shall be utilized.

$2.)$ Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue-measure in $\mathbb R^2$. Show that $\mathbb R \times \{0\} \in \mathcal L^2$ and $\mu(\mathbb R \times \{0\})=0$.

$3.)$ We know that there is a non-measurable subset $A \in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)\setminus\mathcal L^1$. From $A$, construct a Lebesgue-measurable set which is not Borel-measurable, that means $B \in \mathcal L^2\setminus \mathfrak B$.

Comment: No hints, anyone?